# MS Access SQL Query - Subtract number value results from union of two queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to query an inventory database to show me how much wax is remaining on hand. Currently this is how I have the query set up:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT SUM(OC.Quantity) AS oz_Wax_Ordered
FROM Order_In AS OC 
WHERE (OC.Component) like ('Wax')
GROUP BY OC.Component

UNION SELECT SUM(C.Wax_Used) AS oz_Wax_Used
FROM Fragrance_Oils AS FO INNER JOIN Candles AS C ON FO.FragranceID = C.Fragrance
GROUP BY FO.Component
);
```

This shows me a single column with the second SELECT statement totaling the wax used, and the third SELECT totaling the wax ordered, displayed in rows 1 and 2, respectively.

I'm trying to have the total wax used subtract from the total wax ordered. I can share more information about the database itself if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sum the values:

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM([oz_Wax]) AS oz_Wax_OnHand
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(OC.Quantity) AS oz_Wax
    FROM Order_In AS OC 
    WHERE (OC.Component) like ('Wax')
    GROUP BY OC.Component

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT -SUM(C.Wax_Used) 
    FROM Fragrance_Oils AS FO 
    INNER JOIN Candles AS C 
        ON FO.FragranceID = C.Fragrance
    GROUP BY FO.Component);
```